# How to export a MySQLtable with a longBLOB column to an Oracle database?

Tags: mysql, oracle, blob, migration

In MySQL I have a table:

```
Select * from Dummy;
```

Columns like below:

```
id name salary binary_col
1    a   100   A.pdf
2    b   200   b.pdf
3    c   300   c.pdf
4    d   400   d.pdf
5    e   500   e.pdf
```

I am using **SQLyog 7.01**. I have 200 records in the MySQL table.

I want export these 200 records and import them into an Oracle database table.

The `binary_col`  data type is `longBLOB`.